# Android app to speak out of my wife's phone without having to call her

Tags: gratis, android, communication

Looking for a free Android "intercom app" that allows me to speak out of my wife’s phone without having to call her. I mean "any time", "any place".

Bonus points if there is a Windows version I can use on my Windows tablet.

Comment: Over the Internet? Or are you in the same network/WLAN? Or should it use the telephone network somehow?

Comment: I did not restrict my question to a subset of circumstances like "local lan". After all, if we were on a local lan, why would I be looking for an alternative to calling her? I could just yell with my voice.

Comment: For example, because yelling might not work if the building has multiple floors. Anyway, that means that both ways, Internet (which needs to be available) and phone (which might involve costs, and blocking the line), would be acceptable? And if the app uses the Internet, I assume that the service has to be hosted (if it’s not peer-to-peer), or is self-hosting an option?

Comment: Yes, basically an equivalent of the "intercom feature" that some phone plans have.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend [Voxer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rebelvox.voxer).

Voxer allows you to send voice messages to each other.  As long as you both have the app open, no action is needed to hear the other person.

The free version even includes a "push to talk" mode, where you just hold down a button and talk.

You can also send photographs with ease.  The latest version even lets you send videos.

If you don't want to keep the app open, and yet want to hear to audio messages as they arrive, you have to subscribe to their "Voxer Pro" service.  It costs $3.99/mo or $29.99/year.  That seems like a lot of money to speak to your wife, given that she's probably not listening anyways.  ;-)

In my experience, Voxer is *semi-reliable*.  It works as expected most of the time, but does not work perfectly all the time.  Based on my experiences, I would not rely on it for critical communications.

Voxer is available for Android, iOS (iPhone, iPad or iPod), and Windows Phone 8 devices.

They also have a website at [voxer.com](http://voxer.com/) where you can login and send/receive messages.  Thus, you would get access with Windows, which you requested.

Here is an image of their phone interface:

[image]

*Image Source: voxer.com*